# Does anyone know what's wrong with this while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm using a while loop to iterate through a string as long as it's within a-z but it doesn't seem to be working? I find it weird because I'm using the same method in another function except for 0-9 and that one is working just fine.

This is the problematic piece of code:

```
int lexicalAnalyzer::analyzeIdentifiers(char* program, int eos){
location = 0;
int num = 0;
int tempNum;

while(location != eos){
    tempNum = 0; //resetting counter
    while(program[location] >= 'a' && program[location] <= 'z'){ #ERROR here Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x101d00000)
        tempNum++; //using  tempNum to catch whether identifiers are being 
found
        location++;
    }

    if(tempNum == 1){
        //meaning only 1 char was caught
        num++;
        identifiers[0] = identifiers[0] + 1;
    }else if(tempNum > 0){
        //meaning char ident was caught
        num++;
        identifiers[1] = identifiers[1] + 1;
    }
    location++;
}//end of while
return num;
}
```

and this is the one that works just fine

```
int lexicalAnalyzer::analyzeIntegers(char* program, int eos){
location = 0;
int num = 0;
int tempNum;

while(location != eos){
    tempNum = 0; //resetting counter
    while(program[location] >= '0' && program[location] <= '9'){
        tempNum++; //using  tempNum to catch whether integers are 
being found
        location++;
    }

    if(tempNum == 1){
        //meaning only a digit was found
        num++;
        integers[0] = integers[0] + 1;
    }else if(tempNum > 0){
        //meaning integer was caught
        num++;
        integers[1] = integers[1] + 1;
    }
    location++;
}//end of while
return num;
}
```

I'm not sure whether there's something wrong  I'm not seeing but I literally copied and pasted the analyzeInteger function and just modified it slightly for analyzeIdentifiers & yet it won't function??

location is a private class variable already initialized

Comment: `location` could be incremented more than once within the outer `while` loop.  If that happens, it might skip over the value `eos` and then the outer `while` loop will not terminate when it should.

Comment: Consider what happens with `analyzeIdentifiers("aa", 2);`.  `analyzeIntegers` has the same bug (consider `analyzeIntegers("11", 2)`) but you may have just been (un)lucky that it didn't crash, depending on what was in the uninitialized memory following your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following changes to your function.

1. Change the first `while` loop's conditional to:

   ```
   while ( location <= eos ) {
   ```

   this will make sure that the loop will be terminated if `location` is incremented in the loop such that it skips `eos`.
2. Change the conditional of the inner `while` loop to add a similar check.

   ```
   while ( location <= eos &&
           program[location] >= '0' && program[location] <= '9' ) {
   ```
3. Use `std::isdigit` instead of using hard-coded numbers.

   ```
   while ( location <= eos && std::isdigit(program[location]) ) {
   ```

---

An additional check for the terminating null character in `program` in the outer loop will be still better.

```
    while ( location <= eos &&
            program[location] != '\0' ) {
```

Comment: Yup got it! Thanks everyone who commented! I still have a question though, why would you suggest to check for that null character? I would assume once `program[location] = '\0'` that wouldn't fall under a - z, therefore breaking the loop immediately?

Comment: And, finally, instead of hard-coding magic numbers (numbers that assume a particular character encoding), use `std::islower` and `std::isdigit`.